# jquery object get value by known key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

```
Object { "07.03.2022": "106", "08.03.2022": "114" }
```

i want to get the value (e.g. 114) from the known date 08.03.2022

I've already managed to do it the other way around:

```
const keyx = Object.keys(response.activeDates)[Object.values(response.activeDates).indexOf('114')];
```

but how can i get the 114 as result from the known 08.03.2022 ?

this don´t work:

```
var xto = "08.03.2022";
console.log(response.activeDates.xto);
```

Thanks!

Comment: if the object in the question can be called as `data` then `data["08.03.2022"]` will give you `"114"`

Comment: I'm a little surprised you used `.keys(d)[.values(d)..]` but didn't try the reciprocal `.values(d)[.keys(d)...]` :  `Object.values(response.activeDates)[Object.keys(response.activeDates).indexOf("08.03.2022")]` - while this does work, it's not ideal and not needed, but seems the obvious step from what you have that's working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this:

```
console.log(response.activeDates[xto])
```

When you are using `xto` it will look for the key named `xto` and not the value of that variable.

Comment: To add: the attempted `response.activeDates.xto` is the equivalent of `response.activeDates["xto"]` (extra quotes)